# How to get last order date and email user for each users with role 'customer' in woocommerce

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to get last order date and email user for each users with role 'customer'.

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_nicename, wp_users.user_email 
FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta 
ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%customer%' 
ORDER BY wp_users.user_nicename
```

Now i have only users but i need connect it with orders and get last order date.

Comment: Hi! Kindly include your table structure (as text not as an image) and some sample data. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution with WooCommerce function if you can use it instead of custom SQL.

```
$args = array(
 'role' => 'customer',
 'number' => -1,
);

$query = new WP_User_Query($args);

foreach ($query->get_results() as $user){

    $customer = new WC_Customer( $user->ID );
    $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();
    $order_data   = $last_order->get_data();

}
```